# How to cache images for offline display in a browser control in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I want to retrieve some HTML content from the web (for example RSS feed), save it for offline use and then display it in a Web Browser control in a Windows Phone application. I can easily save the content as a string and use NavigateToString() method to display the HTML but what do I do with the images? I can download them and save them and even replace the src attribute of the img tags but how do I intercept the image loading in the web browser control and feed it images from the local database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended parsing the HTML downloading the images and replacing the src attribute with the local file name. Then I saved the html in the local storage so that relative links continue to work. Sadly I did not find a way to store the content in the database because if I used NavigateToString to provide the HTML I cannot provide the image data.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have problem with any asset, not only images (unless you're talking about HTML without any external javascript or CSS). You could possibly have a method to detect asset sources (`<script src="">` or `<img src="">` or `<link href="">` are some obvious examples). Then you would download that asset as a local file. Then when you're displaying it, you would replace all assets in your HTML string with local copies instead.

I haven't worked on Windows Phone at all but I think your solution would be around these lines.

Comment: This is what I was planning to do. Problem is you can't just save files in WP you need to use Isolated Storage and there should be some way to reference it for the web browser control. In addition I want to use the local database so basically I want to pass a byte array for the image.

Comment: I see, if I understand correctly, one big problem you have is the layout of images. You will place image widgets in place of images on the webpage, but then you don't know their sizes or location. Is that correct?

Comment: I haven't even thought about that yet. For now I am fighting the problem of caching images for offline use. It is trivial to cache the HTML (it is in fact HTML from RSS feed so it does not have a lot of external resources) and it is not hard to download the images and store them and even replace the src attributes. But then how do I reference the images in the (now local) html? It is easy to do that when you create content for your app and put it in the package but you cannot programmatically write plain files on WP and even if I could I was hoping to use a local database and not a file.

Comment: Well it wouldn't really matter if you had one asset or a thousand of them, it's the same burder code-wise. It might be a very naive suggestion but I can think of a dirt hack for displaying images. When you first load the content, execute a javascript method on it to detect all images and their locations (or you could alter the HTML to populate width, height values for each <img ..) Now that you have this data, display your HTML and place image widgets on top of it, using the layout data you gathered using your JS method

Comment: This seems like very complex solution but who knows if nothing else works... :)